# Creating an interactive Python console in C or C++

Tags: python, c++, c

I am create an application to send string to Python and read back the result as string again. Following the documentation;

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

I am simply trying to achieve an interactive Python console in C or C++. My problem is that `PyRun_SimpleString` is a one-shot function but I want my application to be interactive and continuous through the session. Can you give me a simple example of an interactive Python shell written in C or C++?

Comment: Why don't you create a loop where you print a prompt and then read user input and then call `PyRun_SimpleString`?

Comment: @user19095524 The first line of your code: #define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried that as well but could not get the output of the result to a string variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:

```c
// Set up an interactive Python shell
printf("Starting Interactive Python Shell...\n");
printf("Type 'exit()' or press Ctrl-D to exit.\n\n");
PyRun_InteractiveLoop(stdin, "<stdin>");
```